# Emulator for a WAP?

Tags: emulation, wap

Is there any stand alone WAP emulator to emulate waop website for Nokia 6600 and Sony Ericsson MIDP handset ?

I am creating a WAP portal, and I dont feel like upload all my files on the web every time and then loading it on opera mini demo emulator.

I guess there should be something standalone software to emulate these files ?

P.S - I am a PHP Developer so I don't know anything about JAVA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another very good one(that I use), is [WinWAP](http://www.winwap.com/presentation/products). They have SDKs, emulators and a real browser.

Answer (score 1):

People are still doing WAP? Hmm, [maybe - maybe not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109922/is-wap-dead).

You could try the Openwave SDK. Openwave sold their browser business to PurpleLabs last year (now Myriad Group) and there appears to be no further development on the SDK (which is a shame, as I was one of the SDK developers back in 2001). However I see that [someone uploaded their own copy of the SDK binaries to the WAP Review forums](http://wapreview.com/blog/?p=3733). (Interesting bit of history there in that post too).

Oh, I should add that the Openwave SDK has a full WAP emulator, allowing you to browse local wml and xhtml files in a device emulator (running the Openwave mobile browser codebase).

Comment: thanks for the links, yes some people still use internet on GPRS hence the need of WAP

Answer (score -2):

You can also download the free WinWAP 4.2 browser (full WAP support on your PC) from http://www.winwap.com/presentation/products

Comment: This is a duplication for the above answer. Please read other people answers before commenting.